# How can I add Custom Attribute in razorpay

Tags: reactjs, express, mern, razorpay

How can I add a custom attribute like order_id email phone amount to razorpay dashboard.
[Ref Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpGKN.png) .Like here in the image there is a custom column   Order Id how can I add it?

razorpayutils.js

```
import { loadScript } from './utils';
import Logo from '../../../Drawables/Banner/Logo.png';

export const initiateRazorpayPayment = async (data) => {
  console.log("data", data.totalPrice);

  // Make an API call to your server-side to create a Razorpay order
  const response = await fetch('/create-order', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      amount: data.totalPrice.replace('.', ''),
      //email: data.email,
    contact: data.contact,
    contact1: data.totalPrice,
    username:data.User_Name,
    db_id: data.db_id, // Include db_id as a parameter
    }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
  console.log('Razorpay order creation response:', response);
  const responseData = await response.json();
  const orderId = responseData.orderId; // Retrieve the generated order ID

  console.log("Order ID:", orderId);
  console.log("DB ID:", data.db_id); // Log the db_id
  if (window.Razorpay) {
    const options = {
      key: 'rzp_test_aHOdspgUyROspi',
      amount: data.totalPrice.replace('.', ''),
      currency: 'INR',
      name: 'Shop Now',
      description: 'Payment for your order',
      image: Logo,
      db_id:responseData.db_id,
      order_id: orderId, // Use the generated order ID
      handler: function (response) {
        console.log("This is resp>>",response);
      },
      prefill: {
        email: data.email,
        contact: data.contact,
        username:data.User_Name,
        db_id:responseData.db_id,
      },
      notes: {
        db_id:responseData.db_id,
       username : data.User_Name
      },
      db_id: {
        db_id:responseData.db_id
      },
    };

    const rzp = new window.Razorpay(options);
    rzp.open();
  } else {
    console.log('Razorpay script not loaded.');
  }
};

export const loadRazorpayScript = () => {
  loadScript('https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js', () => {
    console.log('Razorpay script loaded.');
  });
};
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Razorpay = require('razorpay');

// Create a new instance of Razorpay
const razorpay = new Razorpay({
  key_id: process.env.RAZORPAY_ID_KEY,
  key_secret: process.env.RAZORPAY_SECRET_KEY,
});
router.use(express.json());
// Endpoint to create a Razorpay order
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.body)
  console.log(req.body);
  const { totalPrice, email, contact,contact1,username,db_id} = req.body;

  try {
    // Create an order using Razorpay API
    console.log("price",contact1)
    const razorpayOrder = await razorpay.orders.create({
      amount: parseInt(contact1.replace('.', '')), // Convert to paise
      currency: 'INR',
      receipt: 'order_receipt',
      notes: {
        email,
        contact,
        username,
        db_id, // Include db_id in the notes
      },
    });
    console.log('Razorpay order creation response:', razorpayOrder);

    const orderId = razorpayOrder.id;
    console.log("KKKKKKKKK",orderId);
// Log the db_id
    console.log("DB ID:", db_id);
    // Return the order ID in the response
    res.json({ orderId,db_id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create Razorpay order' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have no idea how its done ,I asked chatgpt no solutions he is suggesting me to add db_id to notes but thats not what i want I want to display it on dashboard like other fields email,phone,status,...I searched it on google but no luck now I m exhausted  please guide me